# Matching regex for positive and negative numbers with floating point

Tags: jquery, regex

I have tried to make regex for positive and negative numbers with floating point

What I tried is:

```js
var pattern = new RegExp('(^[-+]?([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+))$');
```

Here I tried it and almost achieved my goal but one thing that I want to know where I am wrong.

I tried the strings shown below:

```js
pattern.test("1");
false
pattern.test("11");
false
pattern.test("111");
true
pattern.test("11.11");
true
pattern.test("-11.11");
true
pattern.test("+11.11");
true
pattern.test(".11");
false
pattern.test("+12414.11");
true
```

All are getting right excepting the first two strings that failed to match

Can any one can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(^[-+]?([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?)$'` is what you can use

Comment: can you tell me please dude where i was going wrong so it was taking "111" but  "11" and "1" not..???

Comment: I added `?` between last two brackets to chose between one of preceding tokens

Comment: i knw it's working though i want to know how it makes difference coz i am excited with whenever RegEx comes as a bug to me so can you help me for that.?