# Compose a regexp for positive and negative integers, floats

Tags: javascript, regex

Compose a `regexp` for integers, floats, negative integers.

From a string like this: `2-1+7*-777/-0.001+0.99` I need to get an array:

```
["2", "1", "7", "-777", "-0.001", "0.99"].
```

I'm trying to use this code:

```
var str = "2-1+7*-777/-0.001+0.99";
var array = str.match(/(?:\*|\/|\+|\-)(-\d+(\.\d+)?)|(\d+\.\d+)|(\d+)/g);
```

But the problem is that the result is:

```
["2", "1", "7", "*-777", "/-0.001", "0.99"]
```

Special attention to `*-777` and `/-0.001`

I don't need operation symbols before negative numbers in this array. Only negative (with '-') and positive (without '+') floats and integers.

I don't need to match '-1' in '2-1' but I need to match '-1' in '2*-1'.

Also I need a solution that works not only in Chrome.

---

This is no dupe of  [Matching regex for positive and negative numbers with floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31200214/matching-regex-for-positive-and-negative-numbers-with-floating-point)

I am trying to parse numbers out of a calculative term. I need to get the negative sign before a number *ONLY* if they appear **after** a division `/` or multiplication `*`. The linked answers regex can **not** do this, it will find **all** negative numbers.

(Edit: P.Artner from comments to my proposed solution)

Comment: How many regexes have been written to match numbers, do you think? Hundreds? Thousands? More? Have you tried any of the existing ones?

Comment: This is not duplicate question. There could be thousands of number parsing regex solution in this forum... but this doesn't seem like to be a exact one. Just because there are other number parsing problem , it should not be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following approach:

```
(?:[*/](-[\d.]+))|([\d\.]+)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/K2zCNv/1)

```js
const regex = /(?:[*/](-[\d.]+))|([\d\.]+)/g;
const str = `2-1+7*-777/-0.001+0.99`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {

if(m[1]!=null)
console.log(m[1]);
else if(m[2]!=null)
console.log(m[2]);

}


//["2", "1", "7", "-777", "-0.001", "0.99"].
```